# Haskell Yesod: Sending a Post Request On Image Click

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am writing a simple website in Haskell with Yesod. I have the following hamlet

```html
<ul id="gallery">
              $forall file <- listOfFiles
                  <form action=@{CharacterUpdateR} method="POST">
                      <input type="hidden" name="Name" value=#{characterName character} />
                      <input type="hidden" name="Portrait" value=#{file} />
                      <input type="hidden" name="Description" value=#{fromMaybe "" (characterDescription character)} />
                      <input type="image" src=#{imageFilePath $ (++) (unpack $ characterName character) ((++) "\\"  file)} name="select" alt="select" />
```

The following Haskell code is supposed to handle the request:

```hs
postCharacterUpdateR :: Handler Html
postCharacterUpdateR = do
    ((result, widget), enctype) <- runFormPost updateCharacterForm
    case result of
        FormSuccess (name, file, desc) -> do
            _ <- runDB $ updateWhere [CharacterName ==. name] [CharacterPortrait =.   file] 
            _ <- runDB $ updateWhere [CharacterName ==. name] [CharacterDescription =. desc]
            setMessage "Character Updated"
            redirect CharactersR
        _ -> do
            liftIO $ putStrLn $ show result
            setMessage $ "Something went wrong: "
            redirect CharactersR
```

The page renders fine and when the images in the gallery are clicked, a POST request is sent and received by the handler, but it always fails, with the following error message: `FormFailure ["Value is required","Value is required"]`

I have tried to send the post request via a Julius widget instead with ajax, but reached a similar problem.  In the developer console, it seems like the payload for the sent POST request is fine, but nonetheless the handler never receives the POST parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by, rather than using Hamlet itself to create the form submission, using runFormPost to get a widget to send the request.

```
updateCharacterForm :: Text -> String -> Maybe Textarea -> Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult (Text, Text, Maybe Textarea), Widget)
updateCharacterForm name portrait desc = renderBootstrap $ (,,)
             <$> areq hiddenField "Name" (Just name)
             <*> areq hiddenField "Portrait" (Just $ pack portrait)
             <*> aopt textareaField "Description" (Just desc)
```

In conjunction with

````
characterGalleryEntry :: Character -> String -> Widget
characterGalleryEntry character file = do
  ((_, widget), enctype) <- liftHandler $ runFormPost (updateCharacterForm (characterName character) file (characterDescription character))
  [whamlet|$newline never
                  <form action=@{CharacterUpdateR} method=post enctype=#{enctype}>
                      ^{widget}
                      <image src=#{imageFilePath $ (++) (unpack $ characterName character) ((++) "\\"  file)}>
                      <input .btn type=submit value="Set Profile Picture and Update">
|]```
For the post itself
````